# I cant unlock a vbaproject with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Down below is my function, for some reason it does not work. If I place a breakpoint in the last if statement and removes sending "%{F11}" it does work. So my guess is that "%F11" is not working. Does anyone have an idea?

```
Sub UnprotecPassword(wb As Workbook, ByVal projectPassword As String)
    Dim currentActiveWb As Workbook    

    If wb.VBProject.Protection <> vbext_pp_locked Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set currentActiveWb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Activate

    SendKeys "%{F11}"
    SendKeys "^r" ' Set focus to Explorer
    SendKeys "{TAB}" ' Tab to locked project
    SendKeys "~" ' Enter
    SendKeys projectPassword
    SendKeys "~" ' Enter

    If (wb.VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_locked) Then
        MsgBox ("failed to unlock")
    End If
    currentActiveWb.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Change `vbext_pp_locked` to `1` 2) Call the above sub from a macro which is invoked from a Macros toolbar and not from VBA Editor and it will work. I just tested it and it works

Comment: thanks, what exactly do you mean with nr 2, Im new to vba so please explain a little bit more:)

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Ok gimme a moment. Explaining it with screenshots :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test this, Let's create a new workbook called `Book2.xlsm`.

for testing purpose paste this code in the Book2 Module.

```
Sub Book2Macro()

End Sub
```

Protect it with a password say `a` and then close it. This is necessary for the Locking to take effect.

Now create a new workbook say Book1 and in the module paste this code.

```
Sub Sample()
    UnprotecPassword Workbooks("Book2.xlsm"), "a"
End Sub

Sub UnprotecPassword(wb As Workbook, ByVal projectPassword As String)
    Dim currentActiveWb As Workbook

    If wb.VBProject.Protection <> 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set currentActiveWb = ActiveWorkbook

    wb.Activate

    SendKeys "%{F11}"
    SendKeys "^r" ' Set focus to Explorer
    SendKeys "{TAB}" ' Tab to locked project
    SendKeys "~" ' Enter
    SendKeys projectPassword
    SendKeys "~" ' Enter

    If (wb.VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_locked) Then
        MsgBox ("failed to unlock")
    End If
    currentActiveWb.Activate
End Sub
```

Now open the 1st workbook that we created; Book2.xlsm. Check the VBA Editor for Book2 and you will notice that it is password protected. You will also notice that it is the active workbook. Activate `Book1` by clicking the `View Tab | Switch Workbooks | Book1`

[image]

Now click on `Developer tab | Macros` If you can't see Developer tab then I would recommend going through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx).

[image]

Click on the the `Sample` Macro in the `Macro Dialog Box` and you are done.

[image]

If you check the VBA Editor, you will notice that the VBA Editor for Book2 is now unlocked/accessible.

Sendkeys are unreliable depending on your use of it. If you use it correctly then that are pretty much reliable :)

There is one more way to unlock the VBA Password but that is pretty complex and involves invoking the API like FindWindow etc...

Answer (score 0):

Check out these posts for code samples:
http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/29825.html
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30687

And these posts are for info:
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/490883-why-doesnt-sendkeys-work-consistently.html
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13006

They discuss why using Sendkeys is not very reliable in a multitasking environment and many discourage the use for commercial purpose. 
However, for unprotecting VBA projects, it appears to be the only solution.

Hope it helps!